# Как это называется?

Tags: плагин, notepad++, редактор

Здравствуйте.

Видел плагины для текстовых редакторов, которые создавали теги на основании такой команды:

`ul.ul-class-1>li.li-class-1+li.li-class-2+li.li-class-3`

Данная команда создаст на странице примерно такой код:

```
<ul class="ul-class-1">
    <li class="li-class-1"></li>
    <li class="li-class-2"></li>
    <li class="li-class-3"></li>
</ul>
```

Как это называется?

Comment: Если вам нравится такой стиль, то удобнее будет использовать [pug](https://pugjs.org) вместо html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

называется zen coding. Вот пример https://www.davidtan.org/how-to-install-use-zen-coding-in-notepad-faster-html-css-coding/